# Understanding the "self" in classes for Python

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list, reversing

I'm trying to understand the solution provided for reversing a linked list. In particular, I don't get why for the very last line we write:

```
self.head=prev
```

and not

```
current=prev
```

since

```
current=self.head
```

I know my reasoning is flawed, that's why I came here for help. Thank you in advance.

```
class Node: 

    # Constructor to initialize the node object 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None

class LinkedList: 

    # Function to initialize head 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None
  def reverse(self): 
        prev = None
        current = self.head 
        while(current is not None): 
            next = current.next
            current.next = prev 
            prev = current 
            current = next
        self.head = prev
```

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html - rebinding a local variable is not the same as assigning to an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is not equality like in math, it is the assignment/binding operator.

Therefore, after:

```
current=self.head
current=prev
```

`current` will have the value of `prev` and `self.head` will have nothing to do with `current` nor will be modified.

Comment: So in Python if A=B and B=C, that does not make A=C. A and C have nothing to do with each other. Is that correct?

Comment: @VictorGaina Yes, in Python and in all programming languages where `=` represents assignment.